# Can my "add_action" function know the name of the hook calling it?

Tags: actions

Lots of hooks:

```
add_action('thesis_hook_after_comment', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_comments', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_comment_box', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_comment_meta', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_content', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_content_area', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_content_box', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_footer', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_header', 'pj_time');
add_action('thesis_hook_after_headline', 'pj_time');
// etc.
```

How can `function pj_time()` know which hook called it?  Is there a global variable or something that tells me which hook we're on?  So pj_time() could output something like: "The hook (name of hook here) rocks."

I don't know the order the hooks are called either, they're just in alphabetical order here. Otherwise I could use a counter to figure how many hooks we've done so far and determine the name of the hook that way.

So I want to know if it's possible to get the name of the hook.  Thanks.

Comment: Here's the source of what I was attempting to do http://pjbrunet.com/microtimers-on-hooks-to-measure-wordpress-performance/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function pj_time () {
    echo current_filter();
}
```

Easier than I thought ;-)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_filter

Comment: +1 Another cool thing is that you can use that to remove functions and methods as well: `remove_function( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );` and `remove_function( current_filter(), array( $this, __FUNCTION__ ) );`. Only problem is that you'd still have to extract the priority if it's not `10`.

Comment: Sure. We use it in our [WCM Language switcher plugin](https://github.com/wecodemore/wcm_lang_switch/blob/0be2a17ef6e5c16c1bcba1d04c2ba93edc841551/wcm_lang_switch.class.php#L118).

Comment: Dude, PJ Brunet, You're awesome. This little bit of code just saved me. I wanted to find a way to create an ACF repeater that you can choose the section of the page, and then made a bunch of action hooks to output the sections.

But I couldn't figure out how to get the function to figure out the hook it was on. This did the trick perfectly. You're the king.